# Can you play 1 game with 2 paid accounts on 2 ps4's?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Is it possible to play 1 game with 2 ps4's and 2 paid accounts through shareplay (local)?
I read something about this, but it's in Dutch. Here it is:

> "Het is echter ook mogelijk om via Shareplay lokale multiplayer online te spelen. Dan zijn wel twee PS Plus-abonnementen vereist."

Which means something like:

> "But it is also possible to play local online multiplayer through shareplay, but you need 2 PS Plus-subscriptions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't have a PS4 so I can't test this out, but according to [this article](http://www.digitalspy.co.uk/gaming/feature/a605473/ps4-share-play-what-you-can-and-cant-do-while-sharing-a-game.html#%7EoU1K1Wh0u0IvxA) yes

Summary:

Shareplay only works with two players for a maximum of 60 minutes at the moment, but plans to develop and extend

> while it has some constraints - such as PlayStation Plus requirements, 60 minute session lengths, and is limited to two players at launch - it looks to allow games to be shared with another user quickly and easily.

One player (the host) creates a private party and invites the user, then you share (I assume via the share button on the controller), the host continues to play until the invited player joins, from there the host chooses to either let the invited player take control or alternatively play together. Thus a local multi-player game will work online

> When you begin Share Play, a private party must be created and a user on your friends list invited. The host can continue to play the game until the recipient accepts, where by default, the recipient can watch a non-interactive mirror of the host's game.
>
> From there, the Host has two more options with the Share menu. One is handing over control to the user, while the other is to play the game together, so that a local multiplayer game can be played online.

Comment: Ok, that's much and good information, but
I want to ask another thing
Do you think it will work when I got 1 copy of call of duty advanced warfare and that my brother on another ps4 can join with his account and we can play as long as we want together and he can level and stuff like that?

Comment: Well according to the article it should work, but only for an hour. I assume you could just start another party after the hour and invite him. However i'm not sure how leveling would work but it should work normally. Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: Well, ty anyway. You helped me very good.